# Is there a way to put relative sizes of radius of RoundedRectangleBorder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to assign relative value to the `borderRadius` of `RoundedRectangleBorder` as it is the `shape` of a `FlatButton` which is a child of `FractionallySizedBox`. For example: 0.2*size of the box

I also want to do the same for other things like `Text` size.

Is there an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `LayoutBuilder` for that and use the `BoxConstraints` to calculate the required radius.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 400,
  height: 400,
  child: FractionallySizedBox(
    heightFactor: 0.2,
    child: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        final borderRadius = constraints.maxHeight / 5;
        return FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
          ),
          child: Text("Button"),
        );
      }
    ),
  )
);
```

Check out the [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) documentation for more info.

On the other hand, since you want to change the fontSize as well, you might just want to **scale it down** with a `FittedBox`:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 400,
  height: 400,
  child: FractionallySizedBox(
    heightFactor: 0.1,
    child: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
          ),
          child: Text(
            "Button",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 28,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Check out the [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) documentation for more info.

I suggest to try both these approaches, maybe in a simple [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter), and play around with the values.